# Cannot Retrieve The API Result from rawg.io Using JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, get

I'm currently learning API by doing a project that shows list of games from [rawg.io](https://api.rawg.io/api/games) referring to the website's [doc](https://api.rawg.io/docs/).
To call the data from it, i created struct and defining keys in GameFeed.swift & GameDetail.swift

GameFeed.swift :

```
import Foundation
    struct GameFeed: Codable {
        var results:[GameDetail]
    }
```

GameDetail.swift :

```
import Foundation    
struct GameDetail: Codable {
        var id:String?
        var name:String?
        var rating:String?
    }
```

I also defining URLString with URL Link & JSONDecoder() in ViewController.swift

```
    let urlString = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
            guard url != nil else {
        return
    }
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!){
            (data, response, error) in
        
                if error == nil && data != nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let gameFeed = try decoder.decode(GameFeed.self, from: data!)
                
                        print(gameFeed)
            }
            
                    catch {
                        print("Error Parsing JSON")
            }
    }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

When i launch it, i think the data is successfully pulled from website as it shown here

[image: Data 218189 Bytes]

but the end result is "Error Parsing JSON"

[image: Error]

How can i make it possible to retrieve the data and show it to console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the `id` and the `rating` fields as strings, while in the JSON response, they are Int and Double, respectively.

You should change GameDetail.swift so it looks like this:

```
struct GameDetail: Codable {
    var id:Int?
    var name:String?
    var rating:Double?
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhh my, sorry for declaring wrong data type. just testing it out and printed in my console. Thank you so much you just saved my week